# isprint equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c

I'm in the process of migrating the C code in Java code, I need some character handling inbuilt functionality that is available in Character handling

```
What I'm looking for,
isprint -> ??? 

Other I got in java.lang.Character
isalnum -> isLetterOrDigit 
isalpha -> isLetter
```

Can someone help me with finding the isprint equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Character#isISOControl(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28char%29)

> Determines if the specified character is an ISO control character. A
>   character is considered to be an ISO control character if its code is
>   in the range '\u0000' through '\u001F' or in the range '\u007F'
>   through '\u009F'.
>
> **Note:** This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support
>   all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the
>   [Character#isISOControl(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Character.isISOControl (char ch)
```

from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/character_isisocontrol.htm
It returns whether a character is an ISO Control Character.  A character is considered to be an ISO control character if its code is in the range '\u0000' through '\u001F' or in the range '\u007F' through '\u009F'.

Example

The following example shows the usage of lang.Character.isISOControl() method.
package com.tutorialspoint;

```
import java.lang.*;

public class CharacterDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 char primitives ch1, ch2
      char ch1, ch2;

      // assign values to ch1, ch2
      ch1 = ':';
      ch2 = '\u0013';

      // create 2 boolean primitives b1, b2
      boolean b1, b2;

      // assign isISOControl results of ch1, ch2 to b1, b2
      b1 = Character.isISOControl(ch1);
      b2 = Character.isISOControl(ch2);

      String str1 = ch1 + " is an ISO control character is " + b1;
      String str2 = "ch2 is an ISO control character is " + b2;

      // print b1, b2 values
      System.out.println( str1 );
      System.out.println( str2 );
   }
}
```

Let us compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result:

```
: is an ISO control character is false
ch2 is an ISO control character is true
```

Following this, you can use `false` to print the character :)